# php shows code only sometimes

Tags: php

I'm studying PHP (so I'm a rookie). I'm working on a PC (windows 7) with XAMPP, Apache.

I have two files exampleform.html:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and welcome.php:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br />
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old.

</body>
</html>
```

I created those 2 files and worked well. On Monday I encountered the problem that upon clicking the buttom summit query it would show me the code instead the result. I searched few forums and found I need to add the following lines to httpd.conf (xampp/apache/conf/):

AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .php4 .php3 .phtml .php

Then it worked.
Today when I try again it shows me the code once more.
Please help. It can't be so complicated!

Comment: Are you sure your server is running when you try and run the code?

Comment: Yes I can see it is running in XAMPP Control Panel

Answer (score 0):

Is your changes of httpd.conf being inverted? if so, try put them back and restart your apache. If not, then check for your httpd.conf file, make sure php5 module is loaded, you should look for a line look similar like this one:

LoadModule php5_module  libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

Comment: On Monday I included the following line LoadModule php5_module "D:\xampp\apache\modules\php5apache2_2.dll"

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter too soon. It would not work with that line above the addtype lines, so I commented it. Then it worked.

Comment: can you post your httpd.conf?

Comment: The file is too big. I deleted the commented lines, still too big. Is there anyway I can upload the file to you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about XAMPP, but it seems that it overwrites the config file whenever you restart your server (ie. restart Windows).

Try installing [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) instead, which was made for Windows in the first place.

Comment: I'm going to give it a go. Thanks.

Comment: I've install WAMP and the same thing happened.

Comment: sorry, this is weird. I've never heard about this problem before.

Comment: It seems to be working! What I did is going to XAMPP Control Panel and click in SERVICE. I've click Apache and MySQL. Then it worked!